# Multiple or condition in sql store procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to check multiple OR conditions inside if block but its my code inside if block still gets executed even if GUIDStatement is 'ContactDetailsGUID' or  'FILECONTENTSGUID' or 'AccountGUID'.

I have a cursor which keeps assigning single value to GuidStatement variable. So at any given point of time my @GUIDStatements variable will have any single name 
My If condition should not get executed when my GUIDStatement has any of the above value

My if condition is as follows. Please help.

```
IF ( (@GUIDStatements <> 'ContactDetailsGUID') OR (@GUIDStatements <> 'FILECONTENTSGUID') OR (@GUIDStatements <> 'AccountGUID'))
```

Comment: _"its not working"_ is not a problem description. What happened? Why was that not what you wanted? What data are you putting in, and what data do you want to get out? What happens instead? You didn't provide nearly enough information for there to be a question for people to answer.

Comment: For non-null `@GUIDStatements` that condition is always true.

Comment: Updated question. @GUIDstatements keeps getting different guid names.

Comment: Replace or to and?

Comment: I have a cursor which keeps assigning single value to GuidStatement variable. So at any given point of time my @GUIDStatements variable will have any single name.

Comment: @Abhijit Given `x=2`, is the expression `x <> 1 Or x <> 2 Or x <> 3` true or false? What about `x=5`? What about `x=anything`?

Comment: @RogérioCarvalho :- Your solution is also fine sir. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

Run the code below. The first block of code, your code, returns false regardless of the value of @GUIDStatements. The second block, suggestion, returns false if @GUIDStatements is in one of the three values and true otherwise. I think, as I understand your question, thatis what you're looking for. If not please comment and I'll try to clarify.

```
DECLARE @GUIDStatements SYSNAME = N'not';

--
-- your code
-------------------------------------------------
IF (
   (
       @GUIDStatements <> 'ContactDetailsGUID'
    )
    OR
   (
       @GUIDStatements <> 'FILECONTENTSGUID'
    )
    OR
   (
       @GUIDStatements <> 'AccountGUID'
    )
   )
    SELECT N'false'
ELSE
    SELECT N'true';

--
-- suggestion
-------------------------------------------------
IF @GUIDStatements IN ( 'ContactDetailsGUID', 'FILECONTENTSGUID', 'AccountGUID' )
    SELECT N'false'
ELSE
    SELECT N'true';
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
IF @GUIDStatements NOT IN ('ContactDetailsGUID', 'FILECONTENTSGUID', 'AccountGUID')
```

Easier to maintain too.